# How do I create a low pass filter for audio using fft

Tags: python, audio, filtering, fft

I have tried to create a low pass filter for aiff files, but the sound coming out is white noise. I only understand the broad overview of how an FFT works, so I'm guessing my problems are related to that.

Basically I open the audio file (of say a piano loop), convert it to mono, then perform an FFT on the samples, then I tried to remove the upper frequencies by setting them to zero. And finally I perform an IFTT and save the results to a new file.

```
import aifc
import struct
import numpy as np

def getMonoSamples(fileName):
    enter code here`obj = aifc.open(fileName,'r')
    obj.setpos(0)
    numFrames = obj.getnframes()
    myFrames = obj.readframes(numFrames)
    samplingRate = obj.getframerate()
    data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=numFrames*2), myFrames)
    data = np.array(data)
    dataLeft =[]
    for i,x in enumerate(data):
        if i%2==1:
            dataLeft.append(x)
    obj.close()
    return dataLeft,numFrames,samplingRate

def writeMonoFile(fileName,samples,nframes):
    mono_file=aifc.open(file, 'w')
    comptype="NONE"
    compname="not compressed"
    nchannels=1
    sampwidth=2
    mono_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, int(sampling_rate), nframes, comptype, compname))
    print "writing sample aif..."
    for s in samples:
       mono_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', s))
    mono_file.close()

def lpFilter(dataFft):
    new =[None]*len(dataFft)
    for i,x in enumerate(dataFft):
        #if the frequency is above 5000, remove it
        if i>5000:
            new[i]=0
        else:
            new[i]=x
    return new
# get audio samples from a function that converts stereo to mono
sampleData,numFrames,samplingRate = getMonoSamples('beetP2.aif') 
dataFft = np.fft.fft(sampleData)
filtered = lpFilter(dataFft)
invFft = np.fft.ifft(filtered)
invFft = [int(x) for x in invFft]
file = "test.aif"
writeMonoFile(file,invFft,numFrames)
```

I do get a warning: "ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part" but I also get this warning when simply performing a stereo to mono conversion and saving. The audio seems to sound fine until I try to filter it. I'm guessing this is related, but not sure how to get around it.

Any audio sample I filter winds up sounding like white noise instead of a filtered version of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to real-to-complex [`numpy.fft.rfft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html#numpy.fft.rfft) and its inverse [`numpy.fft.irfft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html#numpy.fft.irfft) likely resolves the issue.

As the complex-to-complex DFT transform is applied to the real array `sampleData`, the output array is a complex array `dataFft` of the same size. The first item of this array corresponds to the DC component, the second item to frequency 1/N, the third to 2/N... Nevertheless, the second half of the array should rather be described as components of negative frequencies. Hence, the frequency of the last item of the array is -1/N, the item before -2/N... As described in [what FFTW really computes](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029)

> For those who like to think in terms of positive and negative frequencies, this means that the positive frequencies are stored in the first half of the output and the negative frequencies are stored in backwards order in the second half of the output. (The frequency -k/n is the same as the frequency (n-k)/n.)

As the signal is real, the component of frequency -k/N must be the complex conjugate of the component of frequency k/N. For instance, a cosine wave of frequency k/N gives birth to two equal real components of frequencies k/N and -k/N.

By zeroing the second half of the array, components featuring low negative frequencies are discarded and the array does not correspond to the DFT of a real array anymore. It is not a low pass filter and might explain the resulting white noise. As the inverse DFT is applied, `invFft = np.fft.ifft(filtered)`, its outcome `invFft` is complex, featuring the same size as the original array `sampleData`.

Uisng real-to-complex DFT would turn to the real array `sampleData` into a complex array `dataFft` of about half the size. Zeroing one component of this array means zeroing both the positive and the negative frequency, making sure that the array can still be viewed as the DFT of a real array. This real array can finally be recovered by applying the inverse transform `irfft`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It certainly makes sense that zeroing out the negative half of the frequencies I'm trying to preserve would alter the sound quite a bit. I think you are saying that I should basically just change `dataFft = np.fft.fft(sampleData)`

`invFft = np.fft.ifft(filtered)` to `dataFft = np.fft.rfft(sampleData)`

`invFft = np.fft.irfft(filtered)`. This gives me a result (irfft product) that is about twice the amplitude of the input signal and still just sounds like white noise. Maybe I am missing something?